# Please help me find the maxima of this expression

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, bounded-variation

I want to find   $p$ which maximizes the given functional. $p$ is a function of the form $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.   $\Omega$ is a region in the 2-d plane.

$\underset{p}{\sup} \int_\Omega \{ \lambda(\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{p}) - \alpha(|p| - C)\}\, dx$

Authors of the paper [A Study on Continuous Max-Flow and Min-Cut Approaches](https://bora.uib.no/handle/1956/5020) has said the following to be an equivalent formulation:

$\underset{|p| \le C}{\sup} \int_\Omega  \lambda \vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{p}\, dx$

The authors further claim that it is a well known result that the above is equal to

$\int_\Omega  C|\nabla\lambda|\, dx$

And hence it is the desired answer.

I was wondering if I can get the above answer by some more intuitive approach, or if someone could please explain to me what the authors are trying to say.

Comment: Which author of which paper is claiming all that?

Comment: The second equivalence (which the author suggests is well known) is in the paper " A study on continuous max-flow and min-cut approaches" by Boykov et al. The first equivalence is my understanding of the paper and not necessarily what the author is claiming

Comment: Did you try partial-integration?

Comment: The first equivalence is true when $\alpha(x) = \infty$ for $x \leq 0$, $0$ otherwise. It's a function that's often used in convex optimization, I don't remember the name for it.

Comment: @Fabian: The more common term is "integration by parts". I'm German, I used to think it was called "partial integration", but apparently to native English speakers that sounds like you didn't finish the integration :-) (In German it's "partielle Integration".)

Comment: @joriki: I find both (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialIntegration.html) but it seems integration by parts is much more common...

Answer (score 2):

The author's assertion 
$$\underset{|p| \le C}{\sup} \int_\Omega  \lambda \vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{p}\, dx = \int_\Omega  C|\nabla\lambda|\, dx \tag1$$
is true as long as $\lambda$ is sufficiently regular; being in the Sobolev class $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ is enough. (Being Lipschitz, or having bounded continuous gradient, is more than enough.)

Inequality in one direction follows from integration by parts:
$$ \int_\Omega  \lambda \vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{p}\, dx = 
- \int_\Omega  \nabla \lambda \cdot  \vec{p}\, dx  \tag2$$ and slapping $|\cdot|$ on the right. In the opposite direction, we must produce $\vec p$ with $|\vec p|\le C$ for which $-\nabla\lambda \cdot \vec{p}$ is equal or very close to $C|\nabla\lambda|$. Formally,  $\vec p=-C\nabla \lambda/|\nabla \lambda|$ should work, but some approximation may be necessary to make $\vec p$ smooth. Details can be found in the book by Guisti cited as [20] in the paper (*Minimal surfaces and functions of bounded variation*). There's also Wikipedia article on [Bounded variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation).

The supremum on the left of (1) is the standard definition of *total variation* of $\lambda$; it generalizes the one-dimensional concept of bounded variation. See [Two definitions of "Bounded Variation Function"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/295029/85506)

The problem
$$\underset{p}{\sup} \int_\Omega \{ \lambda(\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{p}) - \alpha(|p| - C)\}\, dx \tag3$$
(with appropriate $\alpha$) is a *relaxation* of the problem in (1). Typically, $\alpha=0$ when the argument is nonpositive, and grows rapidly for positive argument. This means that you are not prevented from taking $|p|>C$, but you'll pay a fine if you do. Relaxation is a common way to approximate constrained optimization problems with unconstrained ones. However, the relaxed problem is not "equivalent" to the original one; it is merely an *approximation*, which may be good or bad depending on circumstances.