# how can you "fix" one of the definitions of a BV function of one variable?

Tags: bounded-variation

Math people:

My question is similar to that in 
[Two definitions of "Bounded Variation Function"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295029/two-definitions-of-bounded-variation-function) .
  If you look at that question, you will notice that people treat definitions (1) and (2) as the same, although (1) has the drawback that you can change $f$ on a set of measure zero and $V_a^b(f)$ changes.  The answer posted to that question states the relationship between the two definitions.  Is there any way to adjust definition (1) so it is equivalent to definition (2)?   For example, $f$ is approximately continuous a.e. (see https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Approximate_continuity).  What if you restricted the $x_j$'s to be points of approximate continuity?

Stefan (STack Exchange FAN)

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize BV functions to be right-continuous.  In this way, they behave as signed analogues to distribution functions of probability measure.

Comment: could you be more specific or give a reference to how this is done?  For example, how would you do it if the domain is $[0,]$, $f = 1$ on rational numbers and $f = 0$ for irrational numbers?

Comment: I think what he means it that you can amend the definition of $BV$ by requiring the function to be right-continuous.

Comment: @Thomas : I posed a very similar question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359946/can-i-make-a-bv-function-right-continous-this-way and eventually answered it myself.